# Does the series $\sum u_n$ where $(-1)^n u_n \geq 0$ and $\left|u_{n+1}\right|<\frac{\left|u_n\right|}{2}$ converge, and if so, what to?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I met with a question:

Let $\left\{u_n\right\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of real numbers satisfying the following conditions:

(a) $(-1)^n u_n \geq 0$, for all $n \geq 1$

(b) $\left|u_{n+1}\right|<\frac{\left|u_n\right|}{2}$, for all $n \geq 13$

Which of the following statements are necessarily true?

1. $\sum_{n \geq 1} u_n$ does not converge in $\mathbb{R}$
2. $\sum_{n \geq 13} u_n$ converges to $0$ .
3. $\sum_{n \geq 13} u_n$ converges to a non-zero real number
4. If $\left|u_{n-1}\right|<\frac{\left|u_n\right|}{2}$ for all $2 \leq n \leq 13$, then $\sum_{n \geq 1} u_n$ is a negative real number

My attempts:

1 st option:

I am sure that $u_{13}<0$ and the series $$\sum_{n \geq 13}u_n=u_{13}+u_{14}+...$$ converges absolutely since $$\sum_{n \geq 13}|u_n|=|u_{13}|+|u_{14}|+... < |u_{13}|(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...)=2|u_{13}|,$$and thus the series converges.

2 nd and 3 rd option:

More over, noting the facts $$u_{14}<-\frac{u_{13}}{2},~u_{15}<-\frac{u_{13}}{2^2},u_{16}<-\frac{u_{13}}{2^3},...,$$
we get $$\sum_{n \geq 13}u_n=u_{13}+u_{14}+...<u_{13}(1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^2}-...)=0$$

4 th option:
I have trouble with this option (seems to be true), how can I use the estimates $$u_{12}<-\frac{u_{13}}{2},~u_{11}<-\frac{u_{13}}{2^2},...,u_{1}<-\frac{u_{13}}{2^{12}},$$ to make the entire sum $\sum_{n \geq 1} u_n <0$?

On the other side, I have
$$u_{1}+u_{2}+...+u_{12} < -u_{13}(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{2^{12}})>0.$$

Any mislead commited here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A series is neither crazy nor sane. It can make **you** crazy.

Comment: $(-1)^n\over3^n$ is an example of a series that fits the description. So is $(-1)^n\over4^n$. See where this gets you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a rearrangement of the terms in the absolutely convergent series $\displaystyle \sum_{n \geq1} u_n$ as $$\displaystyle \sum_{n \geq1} u_n=-a_1+(a_2-a_3)+(a_3-a_4)+...+(a_{12}-\frac{a_{13}}{2})+(-\frac{a_{13}}{2}+a_{14})+(-a_{15}+a_{16})+...$$ $$=b_1+b_2+...+b_{12}+b_{13}+b_{15}+...$$ where $u_n=(-1)^na_n$, with $a_n \geq 0, ~b_1=-a_1,~b_2=(a_2-a_3),$ and so on. Fortunately given conditions provide $b_k<0$ for each $k=1,2,3...$